# How to update Modified By and Created By via web services in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, web-services

How to update the values of Editor or Author fields in a SharePoint list (not a document library) item via web services?

I did read somewhere that updating the fields would be possible for lists (but not for document libraries).

For example, I have understood that it should be possible to update a listitem via Lists.asmx / UpdateListItems and passing Editor and Author fields as ID;#AccountName (15;#DEV\User)

However I don't seem to get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? Those fields are system fields which you shouldn't update..

Comment: For communication between SharePoint and a .NET MVC application in a NTLM on-premises environment (without Kerberos delegation): Users submit an MVC form which initiates a web Service call to SharePoint in order to update a listitem. Here technically MVC IIS process does the updates (NTLM without delegation) so why change created/modified? this is done purely from Ux perspective because end users are creating views to the SharePoint lists, and they expect the editor to be the end user instead of a system account.

Comment: I think one argument not to update the fields would be that we lose audit information from technical perspective (so I clearly understand why this is not easy) but I think here and in similar cases it might nevertheless be better to change those values (with a feasible solution).

Comment: The preferred method would be to make the web service request on behalf of the current user (using their current credentials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services operate under the credentials of the user executing the request. You don't have to pass that information in, Sharepoint will handle it automatically on creation/edit of an item.

Comment: Due to double-hop the credentials of process account would be used in non-Kerberos environments.

Comment: Setting Created By and Modified By fields as non-read-only would solve this but would it cause issues?

Comment: Got this working after updating old Web References to the more recent Service References.